# How to add data in firebase for each user in a separate collection using the ID of user as the name of the collection?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

To be precise about the question, **How can I add data for each user in a separate collection using the ID of user as the name of the collection to prevent the data from being visible to everybody?** I am working in a project in which the user saves their respective data and saves it. Upon saving the data, the data is saved in the firebase in the collection that I have created. What my problem is, the saved data is stored in the collection and the entire data saved by all other users (including different users) is shown to every user. I am looking for something which displays the data saved (in recyclerview in my case) of the particular user rather than displaying all others data stored in the collection.

I believe it happens by creating a separate collection for each user, I have no idea about the implementation of those

I wish I could share many files of java, since I do not want to make it messy and lengthy am just posting a fragment class in which am retrieving the data from firebase. If you need any other files I would love to share. Thanks for reading!

```
package com.cksapp.memoryin;

package com.cksapp.memoryin;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Third extends Fragment {
    View v;


    private RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference noteref = db.collection("Notebook");
    private Adapterrrr adapterrrr;

    public Third() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_third, container, false);
        mRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_interest);

        setuprecyclerview();
        return v;
    }

    private void setuprecyclerview() {
        Query query = db.collection("Notebook");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<CardModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<CardModel>()
                .setQuery(query, CardModel.class)
                .build();


        adapterrrr = new Adapterrrr(options);
        mRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_interest);
        //mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(adapterrrr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       adapterrrr.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapterrrr.stopListening();
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of my firebase]

I have got 3 users right now, all the three users are having the access to data stored in the firebase. So technically the data is added and accessed by every user who registered in my app. I would like to make it data save and retrieve specifically to each user who saved.

[image: users]

So in my case all the users are having the access to data in the recyclerview whoever might have added the data, the data is in common to all the users. How do I make it data specific to the user?

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question here.  If your existing model isn't working, your question should explain specifically what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach would be to create a field named `owner` that will have the value of the `User UID` inside each document:

```
/Notebooks/{notebook_id}

{
  name: "a",
  amount: "2",
  owner: "user_uid"
}
```

and change your query to:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
Query query = db.collection("Notebook").where("owner", "==", user.uid).get();
```

Also it's recommended to add a security rule to avoid reading and writing from unauthenticated users:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Notebooks/{notebook_id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more information on how to secure your documents by a specific user id here: [Secure and query documents based on auth.uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_authuid)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking time and reading my post. I was able to figure out the solution. I have changed a query with respect to the authentication userid and generating a sub collection class for userid.

So, the hierarchy is as follows

1. Main Collection. **Notebook**
2. userid   **userId**
3. **userHourbook** (new collection)

And the change in my query code
*Just the representation of hierarchy*

```
Query query = db.collection("Hourbook").document(user.getUid()).collection("userHourbook");
```